# Android: выполнить Javascript в WebView

Tags: android, javascript, webview

Добрый день, нужно по окончании загрузки страницы в `WebView` автоматически кликнуть по кнопке. Делаю так, но из WebView кнопка кликается, а программно нет. 
Что можно сделать в данной ситуации? 
Спасибо.

```
public class RostelecomLoginActivity extends Activity {

WebView webView;
String url;

@SupressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rostelecom_login);

    Intent webIntent = getIntent();
    final String url = webIntent.getStringExtra("url");

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onPageLoad(WebView view, String url) {
        }

        public void onPageStarted() {
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('mA').click()");
        }

        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            handler.proceed();
        }

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl(url);
}
}
```

Comment: Попробуй просто вставить код яваскрипта в конец загружаемого файла и обернуть в window.onload.

Comment: На входе в почту Ваш код кнопку тискает     
          
     webView.loadUrl("https://accounts.google.com");     
     webView.loadUrl(     
             "javascript:document.getElementById('signIn').click()");     

Значит нужно со страничкой разбираться

Answer (score 1):

Не видно, чтоб webSettings применялись к webView. Я бы попробовал всё-таки

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Та вот оно там как раз то и есть. Присмотритесь.  >WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); Видимо проблема в другом.